# mips load byte when the base memory is mron a register

Tags: mips

I want to load a byte from the memory into a register in mips.
but instead of doing this:`lbu $t0, base($offset)`
I want the base to be a register, like this: `lbu $t0, $a1($offset)`

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `lbu $t0, base($offset)` <-- Where did you get that from? The format listed in the instruction set reference is `LBU rt, offset(base)`, where `offset` is a 16-bit signed immediate and `base` is a register.

Comment: but is there any way for the offset and the base to be a register? or take the value of a register and somehow make him an "immediate"?

Comment: No, there is no two-register addressing mode:  MIPS cannot do this in one instruction.  Whenever we cannot do something in one instruction, the answer is to use more than one instruction.

Comment: then how do you do it in one instruction?

Comment: You cannot do it in one instruction.  Is that not clear?

Comment: I meant how do you do it in more than one instructin...

Comment: Write a sequence of code that accomplishes your intent.  So first, describe your intent, quite literally.  What are you trying to do with the two registers?

Comment: I need to write a function that gets an array of 8 bytes in the $a1 register and prints it. but to print it I first need to load it from the array from the memory. so my question is how can I load the array from the memory when the base and the offset are both registers

Comment: Write out, mathematically if necessary, your intent with the two registers.  What do you want to do with them?

Comment: it is in a loop. so the first register is the address of the array, and the second register is kind of a counter, so the lub operation takes a different element of the array every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Focus on the two registers (and the operation of the instruction you wish you had): how do you want to use those two registers to access the memory of the array?  Perhaps, write it out mathematically.  You want to do an indexing operation, so, mathematically speaking, what is that operation?  It can be decomposed into steps.

Comment: the $a1 register is the base address of the array, and the $t0 register is an iterator that counts up every iteration of the loop. I want to do this: $t1 = mem[$a1 + $t0].

Comment: Very good:  $t1 = mem[$a1 + $t0] is what you want there.  Now break this down into simpler steps, like in [TAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code).  What comes first -- what is the first mathematical operation that has to be done for this?

Comment: Oh, well, just to make sure that I understand, I just need to add the two registers together and use a 0 offset, right?

Comment: Yes.  Like if you wanted `a+b*c` but the processor cannot do that in one instruction, so first you multiply, then add..

Comment: As long as your array elements are 1 byte long this will work.  If the array elements are larger, then because each byte has its own address, you have to scale the index.  A word array, with 4 byte elements, might have its address at 0x1000, then the 2nd element is at 0x1004, third at 0x1008.  So, you can see that the index needs to be multiplied (scaled) by the element size (e.g. 4 for word-sized elements).  For array of bytes, the scale factor is 1, so no separate scaling is needed.