# Iterating through the characters of a string in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

How would I properly iterate through the characters of a defined string in Assembly?
I have tried:

```
lb $t2, $t1($t0)
#$t1 is a number and $t0 is the string
```

However this does not work because $t1($t0) is illegal syntax.

Comment: You need to add them together first. If you don't need to index just iterate, you can of course use `($t0)` and increment it in a loop.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Whenever I try to do lb $t1, ($t0) $t1 is set to 0.

Comment: `addu $t2, $t0, $t1; lb $t2, ($t2)` for example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to Assembly. Could you please elaborate on what this does exactly? I'm familiar with add unsigned and load byte, but not in the way it's used in this context.

Comment: It simply adds `$t0` and `$t1` then loads the byte from that location. Note these are 2 separate instructions.

Comment: If you want to do something but the instruction set will not do it in one instruction, then use a sequence of instructions instead.

Comment: $t0 is declared by using la $t0, input_str, where input_str is a string obtained from syscall. Would this code still work correctly?

Comment: Read the comments in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70815971/471129

Comment: Yes, it doesn't care how you got your string.

Comment: Technically, that's not a declaration, but rather an initialization (and also a repurposing of the register for a new usage).